# Tikz package problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm using the below coding in a Tex file, During compilation it shows the error message (attached screenshot). Could anyone guide me how to solve this problem.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, amsthm, setspace, tikz-cd, hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{TikZ-cd}

\[ \begin{tikzcd} A \ar[r, "\widetilde{\pi}"]\ar[ddr, "\pi"', bend right] & \mathcal{T}(X) \ar[dd, dotted, "\exists\hskip .5pt ! \,\psi"] & X \ar[l, "\widetilde{\tau}"'] \ar[ddl, "\tau", bend left]\\ & & \\ & B & \end{tikzcd} \]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I don't have any problems with your code. It compiles fine. I think some of your packages needs updating.